# Ternary operator - when variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, conditional-operator

I have a fn that creates and populate variable `linkedinInsight` when its invoked.

Just a quick overview of this fn, it will check the response data and see if there is a match. If yes, it would populate the `linkedinInight` variable with the data.

Using Ternary operation, I am unable to display "undefined" when the variable is undefined.
`linkedinInsight === undefined ? "undefined" : "Variable exist"`

However, if the fn gets a match, I could see `"Variable exist"` displayed.

In the case where variable is `undefined`,
from the console, it is showing

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insight_tags')
    at chrome-extension://fpncfpgjnkfnlafmojhhpgophpgikaao/popup.js:13:60
```

The objective here is to present the data and if we couldnt find data, I would like to return a "Data not found message".

Any help guys?

```
document.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  function () {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById("clickIt");
    checkPageButton.addEventListener(
      "click",
      function () {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
          const backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

          const linkedinInsight =
            backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id].insight_tags;


          alert(
            linkedinInsight === undefined ? "undefined" : "Variable exist"
          );
```

Comment: Maybe try `typeof linkedinInsight === 'undefined'` instead of `linkedinInsight === undefined`? Can you tell me if that works?

Comment: The problem is on the line `backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id].insight_tags;` - `backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id]` returns `undefined`, hence when you try to read `insight_tags` from it, you get the error that you cannot read `insight_tags` from `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, Vlaz is right.  

The problem was the error of not reading insight_tags.

Comment: Solution:  was to ensure we resolve the error. 

`const linkedinInsight =
                backgroundPage?.["_linkedin_pixel_data"]?.[tab.id]?.insight_tags;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in below line, replace

```
const linkedinInsight =
            backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id].insight_tags;
```

with

```
const linkedinInsight =
            (backgroundPage && backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"] && backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id] && backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id].insight_tags) || undefined;
```

Or if [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is supported

```
const linkedinInsight =
                backgroundPage?.["_linkedin_pixel_data"]?.[tab.id]?.insight_tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [nullish coalescingm operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
let exists = value ?? `${value} doesn't exist`;
```

If the `value` is `undefined` or `null` then return the value on the right side of operator `??`

```js
function check(X) {
  let present = X  ?? `"X" does not exist`;
  let limit = X < 10 && X > 0 ? `"X" is within range` :  `"X" is out of range`;
  if (typeof present == 'string') {
    console.log(present);
    return;
  }
  console.log(limit);
}

check(5);
check(10);
check(-1);
check();
check(null);
```

Comment: The problem here is that `linkedinInsight` is neither `null` nor `undefined`. The code throws an error before it's even assigned.

Comment: How about `let linkedinInsight = null` early on?

Comment: Erm, `backgroundPage["_linkedin_pixel_data"][tab.id].insight_tags;` would still throw an error?

Comment: Yeah, I got cross-eyed  looking at it and forgot I saw it as a coping mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work in my case.

```
  const paths = data
    ? data.map((item) => ({
        params: { slug: item.attributes.slug },
      }))
    : [];
```

From my understanding below will work also (optional chaining operator (?.) and Nullish coalescing operator (??))

```
  const paths =
    data?.map((item) => ({
      params: { slug: item.attributes.slug },
    })) ?? [];
```